# Ansible inventory same server in multiple groups, execute a task multiple times

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have Ansible inventory as below:

```ini
[all]
[zookeeper]
host1
host2
host3
[broker]
host1
host2
host3
host4
[schemaregistry]
host2
host3
[ksql]
host5
host6
[connector]
host4
[restproxy]
host5
host6
[controlcenter]
host1
```

The group names are services installed on a server.  A server can have more that one service installed. Through my playbook I expect to execute task of only one server group. For example, when I limit the playbook execute of server group `[controlcenter]` which has `host1`, the execution is done for other group also which has `host1` in them.

How can I avoid this behavior?

```bash
ansible-playbook certificate_expiry_calculator.pb -i  /home/ansible/inv_dev.yml -l controlcenter
```

this gives me results for `controlcenter` as well as for `broker` and `zookeeper`.

The playbook is

```yaml
# FOR SIT
#
# source /home/ansible/highlight.sh;ansible-playbook /home/ansible/certificate_expiry_calculator.pb -i  /home/ansible/inv_sit.yml |grep msg| sed 's/\\n/\n/g'|sed 's/\\r//g'|sed 's/\\t/     /'|sed 's/"msg": "//g'|sed 's/"//g'|sed 's/^    //g'|column -t|highlight red `date +%Y`|sed "s/^/         /"

# FOR DEV
#
# source /home/ansible/highlight.sh;ansible-playbook /home/ansible/certificate_expiry_calculator.pb -i  /home/ansible/inv_dev.yml |grep msg| sed 's/\\n/\n/g'|sed 's/\\r//g'|sed 's/\\t/     /'|sed 's/"msg": "//g'|sed 's/"//g'|sed 's/^    //g'|column -t|highlight red `date +%Y`|sed "s/^/         /"

- hosts: broker
  tasks:
  - name: calculate keystore expiry for broker
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    shell: |
      keystore_location=`cat /etc/kafka/server.properties|grep keystore.location|cut -d "=" -f2|head -1`
      #keystore_pwd=`cat /etc/kafka/server.properties|grep ssl.keystore.password|cut -d "=" -f2|head -1`
      keystore_pwd="zzz"
      /usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd 2>/dev/null | grep Alias | awk '{print $3}' | while read ALIAS
      do
          EXPIRACY=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null| grep Valid`
          UNTIL=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
          UNTIL_SECONDS=`date -d "$UNTIL" +%s`
          UNTIL_DATE=`echo $UNTIL|sed 's/ /-/g'`
          REMAINING_DAYS=$(( ($UNTIL_SECONDS - $(date +%s)) / 60 / 60 / 24 ))
          THRESHOLD=`date -d "\`date -d "+90 days"\`" +%s`
          if [[ $THRESHOLD -le $UNTIL_SECONDS ]]; then
              #printf "${BRIGHT}${GREEN}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n" >> ../certificate_expiry_dates
              printf "BROKER : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
          else
              printf "BROKER : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}${RED}[WARNING] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
              RET=1
          fi
      done
    register: output
  - debug:
      msg="{{output.stdout}}"
- hosts: zookeeper
  tasks:
  - name: calculate keystore expiry for zookeeper
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    shell: |
      keystore_location=`cat /etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties|grep keyStore.location|cut -d "=" -f2|head -1`
      #keystore_pwd=`cat /etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties|grep ssl.keystore.password|cut -d "=" -f2|head -1`
      keystore_pwd="zzzz"

      /usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd 2>/dev/null | grep Alias | awk '{print $3}' | while read ALIAS
      do
          EXPIRACY=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null| grep Valid`
          UNTIL=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
          UNTIL_SECONDS=`date -d "$UNTIL" +%s`
          UNTIL_DATE=`echo $UNTIL|sed 's/ /-/g'`
          REMAINING_DAYS=$(( ($UNTIL_SECONDS - $(date +%s)) / 60 / 60 / 24 ))
          THRESHOLD=`date -d "\`date -d "+90 days"\`" +%s`
          if [[ $THRESHOLD -le $UNTIL_SECONDS ]]; then
              #printf "${BRIGHT}${GREEN}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n" >> ../certificate_expiry_dates
              printf "ZOOKEEPER : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
          else
              printf "ZOOKEEPER : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}${RED}[WARNING] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
              RET=1
          fi
      done
    register: output
  - debug:
      msg="{{output.stdout}}"
- hosts: connector
  tasks:
  - name: calculate keystore expiry for connector
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    shell: |
      keystore_location=`cat /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties|grep keystore.location|cut -d "=" -f2|head -1`
      #keystore_pwd=`cat /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties|grep ssl.keystore.password|cut -d "=" -f2`
      keystore_pwd="zzz"

      /usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd 2>/dev/null | grep Alias | awk '{print $3}' | while read ALIAS
      do
          EXPIRACY=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null| grep Valid`
          UNTIL=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
          UNTIL_SECONDS=`date -d "$UNTIL" +%s`
          UNTIL_DATE=`echo $UNTIL|sed 's/ /-/g'`
          REMAINING_DAYS=$(( ($UNTIL_SECONDS - $(date +%s)) / 60 / 60 / 24 ))
          THRESHOLD=`date -d "\`date -d "+90 days"\`" +%s`
          if [[ $THRESHOLD -le $UNTIL_SECONDS ]]; then
              #printf "${BRIGHT}${GREEN}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n" >> ../certificate_expiry_dates
              printf "CONNECTOR       : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
          else
              printf "CONNECTOR       : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}${RED}[WARNING] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
              RET=1
          fi
      done
    register: output
  - debug:
      msg="{{output.stdout}}"
- hosts: controlcenter
  tasks:
  - name: calculate keystore expiry for control center
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    shell: |
      keystore_location=`cat /etc/confluent-control-center/control-center-production.properties|grep keystore.location|cut -d "=" -f2|head -n 1`
      #keystore_pwd=`cat /etc/confluent-control-center/control-center-production.properties|grep keystore.password|cut -d "=" -f2|head -n 1`
      keystore_pwd="zzz"

      /usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd 2>/dev/null | grep Alias | awk '{print $3}' | while read ALIAS
      do
          EXPIRACY=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null| grep Valid`
          UNTIL=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
          UNTIL_SECONDS=`date -d "$UNTIL" +%s`
          UNTIL_DATE=`echo $UNTIL|sed 's/ /-/g'`
          REMAINING_DAYS=$(( ($UNTIL_SECONDS - $(date +%s)) / 60 / 60 / 24 ))
          THRESHOLD=`date -d "\`date -d "+90 days"\`" +%s`
          if [[ $THRESHOLD -le $UNTIL_SECONDS ]]; then
              #printf "${BRIGHT}${GREEN}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n" >> ../certificate_expiry_dates
              printf "CONTROL_CENTER  : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
          else
              printf "CONTROL_CENTER  : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}${RED}[WARNING] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
              RET=1
          fi
      done
    register: output
  - debug:
      msg="{{output.stdout}}"
- hosts: schemaregistry
  tasks:
  - name: calculate keystore expiry for schema_registry
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    shell: |
      keystore_location=`cat /etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties|grep keystore.location|cut -d "=" -f2`
      #keystore_pwd=`cat /etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties|grep ssl.keystore.password|cut -d "=" -f2`
      keystore_pwd="zzz"

      /usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd 2>/dev/null | grep Alias | awk '{print $3}' | while read ALIAS
      do
          EXPIRACY=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null| grep Valid`
          UNTIL=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
          UNTIL_SECONDS=`date -d "$UNTIL" +%s`
          UNTIL_DATE=`echo $UNTIL|sed 's/ /-/g'`
          REMAINING_DAYS=$(( ($UNTIL_SECONDS - $(date +%s)) / 60 / 60 / 24 ))
          THRESHOLD=`date -d "\`date -d "+90 days"\`" +%s`
          if [[ $THRESHOLD -le $UNTIL_SECONDS ]]; then
              #printf "${BRIGHT}${GREEN}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n" >> ../certificate_expiry_dates
              printf "SCHEMA_REGISTRY : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
          else
              printf "SCHEMA_REGISTRY : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}${RED}[WARNING] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
              RET=1
          fi
      done
    register: output
  - debug:
      msg="{{output.stdout}}"
- hosts: restproxy
  tasks:
  - name: calculate keystore expiry for rest proxy
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    shell: |
      keystore_location=`cat /etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties|grep keystore.location|cut -d "=" -f2|head -n 1`
      #keystore_pwd=`cat /etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties|grep ssl.keystore.password|cut -d "=" -f2|head -n 1`
      keystore_pwd="zzz"

      /usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd 2>/dev/null | grep Alias | awk '{print $3}' | while read ALIAS
      do
          EXPIRACY=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null| grep Valid`
          UNTIL=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
          UNTIL_SECONDS=`date -d "$UNTIL" +%s`
          UNTIL_DATE=`echo $UNTIL|sed 's/ /-/g'`
          REMAINING_DAYS=$(( ($UNTIL_SECONDS - $(date +%s)) / 60 / 60 / 24 ))
          THRESHOLD=`date -d "\`date -d "+90 days"\`" +%s`
          if [[ $THRESHOLD -le $UNTIL_SECONDS ]]; then
              #printf "${BRIGHT}${GREEN}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n" >> ../certificate_expiry_dates
              printf "REST_PROXY : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
          else
              printf "REST_PROXY : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}${RED}[WARNING] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
              RET=1
          fi
      done
    register: output
  - debug:
      msg="{{output.stdout}}"
- hosts: ksql
  tasks:
  - name: calculate keystore expiry for rest proxy
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    shell: |
      keystore_location=`cat /etc/ksqldb/ksql-server.properties|grep -i ssl.keystore.location|cut -d "=" -f2|head -n 1`
      #keystore_pwd=`cat /etc/kafka-rest/ksql-server.properties|grep ssl.keystore.password|cut -d "=" -f2|head -n 1`
      keystore_pwd="zzz"

      /usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd 2>/dev/null | grep Alias | awk '{print $3}' | while read ALIAS
      do
          EXPIRACY=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null| grep Valid`
          UNTIL=`/usr/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore $keystore_location -storepass $keystore_pwd -alias $ALIAS 2>/dev/null | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
          UNTIL_SECONDS=`date -d "$UNTIL" +%s`
          UNTIL_DATE=`echo $UNTIL|sed 's/ /-/g'`
          REMAINING_DAYS=$(( ($UNTIL_SECONDS - $(date +%s)) / 60 / 60 / 24 ))
          THRESHOLD=`date -d "\`date -d "+90 days"\`" +%s`
          if [[ $THRESHOLD -le $UNTIL_SECONDS ]]; then
              #printf "${BRIGHT}${GREEN}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n" >> ../certificate_expiry_dates
              printf "KSQL : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}[OK] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
          else
              printf "KSQL : `hostname` : ${BRIGHT}${RED}[WARNING] : Certificate $ALIAS expires $UNTIL_DATE : days left  $REMAINING_DAYS ${NORMAL}\n"
              RET=1
          fi
      done
    register: output
  - debug:
      msg="{{output.stdout}}"
```

the execution result is

```yaml
ansible@host1[~] $ source /home/ansible/highlight.sh;ansible-playbook /home/ansible/certificate_expiry_calculator.pb -i  /home/ansible/inv_dev.yml --limit controlcenter

PLAY [broker] *****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [calculate keystore expiry for broker] ***********************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "BROKER : host1 : [OK] : Certificate caroot expires Wed-Dec-03-17:49:33-UKT-2042 : days left  7231 \nBROKER : host1 : [OK] : Certificate localhost expires Thu-Dec-12-09:34:06-UKT-2024 : days left  665 "
}

PLAY [zookeeper] **************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [calculate keystore expiry for zookeeper] ********************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "ZOOKEEPER : host1 : [OK] : Certificate caroot expires Wed-Dec-03-17:49:33-UKT-2042 : days left  7231 \nZOOKEEPER : host1 : [OK] : Certificate localhost expires Thu-Dec-12-09:34:06-UKT-2024 : days left  665 "
}

PLAY [connector] **************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY [controlcenter] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [calculate keystore expiry for control center] ***************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "CONTROL_CENTER  : host1 : [OK] : Certificate caroot expires Wed-Dec-03-17:49:33-UKT-2042 : days left  7231 \nCONTROL_CENTER  : host1 : [OK] : Certificate localhost expires Thu-Dec-12-09:34:06-UKT-2024 : days left  665 "
}

PLAY [schemaregistry] *********************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY [restproxy] **************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY [ksql] *******************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************
host1 : ok=9    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As per my understanding play for `broker` & `zookeeper` shouldn't have been executed here.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your statement or result. With yout given inventory file and given command line it is just resulting into the single host1.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow; expanding on `U880D`'s comment, [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) may be a useful reading, as well as the [minimal reproducible example section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using simple `tags` for each server group inside playbook. May be another dirty method, but for now it has worked.

Comment: Indeed, [Playbook Tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html) are not made to give such kind of code a structure. [Use Ansible tags to save time on playbook runs](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-tags-fast-playbook-runs).

Answer (score 0):

> *the execution is done for other group also which has `host1` in them.*

Given the **`zoo.ini`**

```ini
[all]
[zookeeper]
host1
host2
host3
[broker]
host1
host2
host3
host4
[schemaregistry]
host2
host3
[ksql]
host5
host6
[connector]
host4
[restproxy]
host5
host6
[controlcenter]
host1
```

a minimal example playbook **`zoo.yml`**

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} in {{ group_names }}"
```

called with

```bash
sshpass -p ${PWD} ansible-playbook --inventory zoo.ini --user ${USER} --ask-pass zoo.yml --limit 'controlcenter'
```

> *I expect to execute task of only one server group.*

will result into the expected output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************
ok: [host1] =>
  msg: host1 in [u'broker', u'controlcenter', u'zookeeper']
```

> *How can I avoid this behavior?*

The execution is done for the given host and group only. For me it was not possible to reproduce an issue.

---

With the now given playbook and since you are using several `- hosts:`  sections with hard-coded group names, you are actually not [targeting hosts and groups with patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html). According [Playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution) you have more than one play.

The issue is reproducible with the following example

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} in {{ group_names }}"

- hosts: broker
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} in {{ group_names }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [all] ************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************
ok: [host1] =>
  msg: host1 in [u'broker', u'controlcenter', u'zookeeper']

PLAY [broker] *********************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************
ok: [host1] =>
  msg: host1 in [u'broker', u'controlcenter', u'zookeeper']

PLAY RECAP ************************************************
host1                      : ok=2
```

> *How can I avoid this behavior?*

In this case I like to recommend to address the playbook structure itself (annot.: and as it seems to be far away from good readable, maintainable, best practices, idempotency, etc.).

Comment: you already stated this in the comment. why now provide this as an answer? perhaps OP will edit original post...

Comment: "_perhaps OP will edit original post..._", maybe. "_why now provide this as an answer?_", we can just delete this post .... However, the post shows how to create a minimal reproducible example, how to debug such issue, as well provides a guess for a probable cause `- debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} in {{ group_names }}"`, the group membership which is not shown in the original post as the playbook content is missing. Some might learn from it.

Comment: I have added code and the execution log in original question